# When was TLS 1.2 support added to OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, tls1.2

Does OpenSSL 0.9.8x support TLS1.2? I looked at the changelog for OpenSSL but didn't find any information on this: https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html

Comment: OpenSSL 0.9.8 does not support TLS 1.2. Painting with a broad brush TLS 1.2 first appeared in OpenSSL 1.0.1. You have to check the CHANGELOG to see when a particular TLS 1.2 feature was added. The first entry you are looking for is *"Initial TLS v1.2 support"* in OpenSSL listed under *"Changes between 1.0.0h and 1.0.1"*. You can also look for Elliptic Curve support, which are the TLS 1.1 changes. TLS 1.1 did not materially change the protocol (IIRC); but it did add cipher suites that required ECC.

Comment: Indeed, GitHub does not supported OpenSSL of macOS 10.5 anymore.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

On the [official changelog page you provided](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x34), under **Changes between 1.0.0h and 1.0.1  [14 Mar 2012]** you can see *Initial TLS v1.2 support*.

> *) Add TLS v1.2 server support for client authentication.
>        [Steve Henson]
>
> *) Add TLS v1.2 client side support for client authentication. Keep cache
>        of handshake records longer as we don't know the hash algorithm to use
>        until after the certificate request message is received.
>        [Steve Henson]
>
> *) Initial TLS v1.2 client support. Add a default signature algorithms
>        extension including all the algorithms we support. Parse new signature
>        format in client key exchange. Relax some ECC signing restrictions for
>        TLS v1.2 as indicated in RFC5246.
>        [Steve Henson]
>
> *) Add server support for TLS v1.2 signature algorithms extension. Switch
>        to new signature format when needed using client digest preference.
>        All server ciphersuites should now work correctly in TLS v1.2. No client
>        support yet and no support for client certificates.
>        [Steve Henson]
>
> *) Initial TLS v1.2 support. Add new SHA256 digest to ssl code, switch
>        to SHA256 for PRF when using TLS v1.2 and later. Add new SHA256 based
>        ciphersuites. At present only RSA key exchange ciphersuites work with
>        TLS v1.2. Add new option for TLS v1.2 replacing the old and obsolete
>        SSL_OP_PKCS1_CHECK flags with SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2. New TLSv1.2 methods
>        and version checking.
>        [Steve Henson]
>
> *) Initial TLSv1.1 support. Since TLSv1.1 is very similar to TLS v1.0 only a few changes are required [...]

TLS 1.2 support is from OpenSSL version **1.0.1**.

OpenSSL 0.9.8x is lower than 1.0.1 so it does not support TLS 1.2