# SSL error 1409442E downloading file over HTTPS with TIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3. The code below used to work but now I'm getting an error when trying to download a file over HTTPS:

> Error connecting with SSL error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version'

```
var
  ms : tmemorystream;
  ssl : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  source,dest : string;
begin
  source := 'https://www.myaddress.com/myfile.zip';
  dest := 'c:\myfile.zip';
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    if pos('https',source) > 0 then
    begin
      ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
      idh.IOHandler := ssl;
    end;
    idhttp1.get(source,ms);
    ms.savetofile(dest);
    result := 'ok';
  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984539/how-can-we-connect-with-a-website-getting-ssl-error-1409442e (first Google match for "tlsv1 alert protocol version indy").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` uses only TLS v1.0 by default](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/181) and the server is rejecting that. You must explicitly allow newer TLS versions:

```pascal
ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
ssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
idh.IOHandler := ssl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Indy have https support built-in (so no need to create SSL IOHandler, Indy will take care of that automatically). 
Also when dealing with files, it is better to use `TFilestream` instead of `TMemoryStream` because you you will get into trouble when trying to download files that don't fit into memory.

Here is a MRE for you:

```
program SO60578855;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  idHttp,
  Classes,
  System.SysUtils;

var
  Http : TidHttp;
  Fs   : TFileStream;

begin
  try
   Fs := TFileStream.Create('c:\temp\100mb.bin', fmcreate);
   Http := TidHttp.Create(nil);
   try
    Http.Get('https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin', Fs);
   finally
    Http.Free;
    Fs.Free;
   end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
 Readln;
end.
```

Comment: I'm on Delphi 10.3.3 so i guess i'm in an updated Indy version, but still i need the SSL component

Comment: @delphirules https://www.indyproject.org/2014/12/22/new-https-functionality-for-tidhttp/ but you are right, you will need to create the component explicitly since you need to tweak its SSLVersions.