# How to download file using TIdHTTP Indy component?

Tags: c++builder, indy10

I get this error when I try to download a file using TIdHTTP component:

```
First chance exception at $76D8AAF2. Exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message
'Error connecting with SSL.
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'.
Process Project1.exe (3684)
```

I have **Indy version 10.6.2.5341** shipped with Embarcadero Rad Studio 10.1 Berlin.

I'm using **IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL** with those options enabled:

[sslvtlsv1, sslvtlsv1_1, sslvtlsv1_2], but still same error, I also have ssl dlls in my application exe directory (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) version 1.0.2u, got it from this post:

[How can we connect with a website? Getting SSL error 1409442E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984539/how-can-we-connect-with-a-website-getting-ssl-error-1409442e)

And this code I use to download a file:

```
const UnicodeString URL = "https://www.rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-60b1.exe";
    TMemoryStream *ms = new TMemoryStream();

    try
    {
        IdHTTP1->Get(URL, ms);
        ms->SaveToFile("E://winrar.exe");
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete ms;
    }
```

**Update:** I upgraded to Indy version 10.6.2.0 and still have the same SSL problem.

Comment: RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin DID NOT ship with Indy 10.1.5, which predates Berlin by over a decade (and didn't have `sslvTLSv1_1`/`sslvTLSv1_2` yet). You can check the exact version that shipped with Berlin [in the IDE](https://www.indyproject.org/2017/11/15/indy-version-info-added-to-delphi-cbuilder-ide/), but I know that XE4 shipped with 10.6.0.0, and Indy 10.6.2.0 was released just before XE8, so Berlin must have a newer version. I suggest you [upgrade](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) to the latest from [Indy's GitHub repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/)

Comment: After installation I see this error log `[ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'INDYSYSTEM.BPI'`
I also added library path to the compiler.

Comment: There is no `INDYSYSTEM.BPI` file in Indy 10, Indy's packages have version numbers in their filenames, and that includes the BPI files (yes, I know, that is not a good thing, it is an [open issue](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/133)), so in this case `INDYSYSTEM240.BPI`.

Comment: So, what is the solution to this?

Comment: You have a bad package reference in whatever project is trying to use `INDYSYSTEM.BPI`, you need to fix that.

Comment: I followed the intructions in the page you gave me, and ended up having that error, I followed instructions step by step, maybe you can help me.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the instructions, so you must not have followed them correctly, or you missed a step.  Or, you simply have a bad/corrupted project to begin with.

Comment: I re-installed my IDE and checked for Indy version and I found it's 10.6.2.5341. which means it's higher than the version that I upgraded to before which is 10.6.2.0, but why my applications showing me that SSL error I mentioned in my question, can you help please?

Comment: "*which means it's higher than the version that I upgraded to*" - actually no. The last number has historically been an SVN revision number, and [Indy doesn't use SVN anymore, it now uses GitHub](https://www.indyproject.org/2019/11/28/indy-svn-retiring-long-live-github/), so the [last number is no longer populated](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/292). When Indy was in SVN, the last number would get overwritten via a script before being compiled by Embarcadero, Fulgan, etc, but that no longer applies under GIT. No solution has been implemented yet to address this.

Comment: "*why my applications showing me that SSL error I mentioned in my question*" - if you have upgraded to the latest version of Indy 10 and are still getting the same TLS alert, then either you have the `SSLIOHandler` configured incorrectly (please [edit] your question to show your exact setup), or you are using the wrong OpenSSL DLLs (what do the `IdSSLOpenSSL.OpenSSLVersion()` and `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_(0|1|2)_Available()` functions report?).

Comment: Where is Indy directory mentioned in the installation instructions [here](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) in **After Compiling**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224214/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-halocedark).

Comment: I updated my question @Remy Lebeau, please read the **Update**

Comment: Your Update doesn't add any new information that I had asked for.

Comment: I'm using the same setup in my question, I just upgraded to Indy 10.6.2.0, but the same error is not solved

Comment: You did not show how you are creating the `TIdHTTP` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` objects, what properties you are setting for them, etc. I need to see the ACTUAL SETUP you are using.  Also, you didn't answer my earlier question about what the `IdSSLOpenSSL(Headers)` utility functions are actually reporting, so I can't even tell if you are using OpenSSL correctly.

Comment: I solved the problem, I was using open ssl win 64 files from [here](https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries) , when I used win32 it the error is gone now.

Comment: You can't use 64bit DLLs in a 32bit app, and vice versa. If you did, you should have gotten a load error and failed to even connect to the server, let alone get a TLS alert from the server.