# gSOAP throws SSLv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: gsoap, sslv3

We are using one server which is currently gone through TLS 1.2 up-gradation.
Before that, our one tool which is communicating to server via gsoap works fine. Now I am getting SSLv3 alert handshake failure in soap_connect method. More precisely under soap->fopen method. I have also added certificate with for soap_ssl_client_context passing with SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT parameter and also tried with other parameters but no luck.

Can you please help me regarding to it?

Comment: You may want to try gsoap version 2.8.78 which has a small change regarding the default TLS protocol settings depending on the version of OpenSSL used.

Comment: @Dr.AlexRE I observed that I am using OpenSSL 1.0.0e but TLS 1.2 introduced in OpenSSl 1.0.1 found in thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178052/when-was-tls-1-2-support-added-to-openssl. SO just upgrading OpenSSL to 1.1.1 solved my issue. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that I am using OpenSSL 1.0.0e but TLS 1.2 introduced in OpenSSl 1.0.1 found in thread stackoverflow.com/questions/48178052/…. SO just upgrading OpenSSL to 1.1.1 solved my issue.